# Is there a way to count the individual instances of an event per year?

Tags: apache-pig

I am working on Apache Pig to get an understanding of working with large databases.  The specific problem is, I need to count the number of days per year for all years listed in the dataset when the temperature in the recorded area was recorded to be above 80 degrees.

The data is set up in the following manner.
Date        Max Temp

1919-06-03, 36

1919-11-26, 91

1927-09-23, 61

This repeats every day for about 200 years.

Currently, I know that to make this more manageable I will be using the split function, to split the data set based on the temp being above 80 degrees.

```
    SPLIT data INTO max_above_95 if max_t > 80;
```

I also figured that if you can get the year out of the date, you can group by, after splitting to get the intended results and count.
I, however, could not find a method to use the year's chunk of the date.

I need this to in the end output giving each year, and the number of occurrences for that year such as the following:

(1993, 21)

(1994, 7)

(1995, 13)

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTER and then extract the year,group by year,count the occurrences.

```
B = FILTER A BY (A.max_t > 80);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE B.Date,GetYear(B.Date) as Year,max_t;
D = GROUP C BY Year;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as Year,COUNT(C.max_t);
DUMP E;
```